# Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Setup Blocked

Tags: visual-studio

This shows up when i run setup https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv7V7.jpg i've tried running it as administrator but same error appears. Any help?

Comment: Did you install required KB2919355?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer has been already told to the author

Comment: It's better to embed your screenshot.

Comment: He who reads (error messages) has a clear advantage. I think the error message and workaround info given in the picture you posted is perfect and there is nothing we could add to make it easier to understand except, maybe a translation to your native language.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following what the error says and installing `KB 2919355` from the link? Looks like you need to install that before it will allow the installation further.

Comment: its unavailable to download so i updated whole windows from and still getting same error

Comment: You should add that you have downloaded the suggested software and are still getting the same error to your answer. This will give people a better idea what to suggest next.